# hasAlpha vs getAlphaRaster

Tags: java, image, awt

In Java, is it expected to be able to have a `BufferedImage` such that `getColorModel().hasAlpha()` will return true, but `getAlphaRaster()` will return null?

I ask because there's a library I'm using (PDFBox specifically, in the `PDJpeg` class) that breaks on such an image.

In this particular case I'm creating the image very simply using:

```
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("/Users/dan/Downloads/test.png"));
```

I've attached the particular image that's failing for me below this question.

Is there some sort of parameter I can pass to ImageIO or some kind of transformation I can do to my `BufferedImage` after it's loaded so that it won't run into this problem?

I'm running Java 1.7.0_40 if it matters.

Stack trace for completeness:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel.isCompatibleRaster(ComponentColorModel.java:2787)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(BufferedImage.java:629)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDJpeg.createImageStream(PDJpeg.java:159)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDJpeg.<init>(PDJpeg.java:133)
```

[image]

Comment: How does it fail? Where is the stack trace?

Comment: The specific stack trace is internal to PDFBox so I didn't think it was applicable, but specifically it's a `NullPointerException` the root cause of which is that `bi.getColorModel().hasAlpha()` returns true but `bi.getAlphaRaster()` returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. As the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getAlphaRaster%28%29) states:

> This method assumes that for all `ColorModel` objects other than `IndexColorModel`, if the `ColorModel` supports alpha, there is a separate alpha channel which is stored as the last band of image data. If the image uses an `IndexColorModel` that has alpha in the lookup table, this method returns `null` since there is no spatially discrete alpha channel.

Your image is a palette PNG with a transparent index. ImageIO will read this into a `BufferedImage` with `IndexColorModel` (ie., no discrete alpha channel).

You can convert the image to a different `BufferedImage` type (like `TYPE_INT_RGB`), by creating a blank image of the same size, getting its graphics, and draw the original onto it:

```
BufferedImage origininal = ...;
BufferedImage copy = new BufferedImage(original.getWidth(), original.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

Graphics2D g = copy.createGraphics();
try {
    g.drawImage(original, 0, 0, null);
}
finally {
    g.dispose();
}
```

You can probably also pass the image type as an `ImageTypeSpecifier` on the `ImageReadParam` passed to the `ImageReader`. But it requires quite a bit more code for the reading part.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I'm unfortunately far from an expert on image formats and processing.